# .NET: Serialize objects into transactional environment

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, transactions

I need a way to serialize objects in a transactional context.

Given the following pseudo-code:

```
transation.Begin()
try{
    serializeObj(obj1);
    serializeObj(obj2);
    serializeObj(obj3);
}
catch(Exception){
    transaction.RollBack();
}
transaction.Commit();
```

I want that, after this code runs, or all the objects had been serialized or none of then had been serialized.

I dont think TransactionScpe gives me this ability.
I would prefer some built-in .NET mechanism instead some external library.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you serializing your objects to, database?

Comment: The objects are serialized to file system.

Comment: The file system is not transactional. But you could serialize to a temp file and then do a rename as your last step. That is quite close.

Comment: The problem remains.. Something could work wrong while renaming the last file.

Comment: Serialize all objects to the same file, or create a lock file during the serialization process. Then you can look if you have a lock file before reading objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a transactional filesystem ([transaction ntfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS)), I think you can achieve what you want via the methods discussed in [this](http://www.improve.dk/blog/2009/02/14/utilizing-transactional-ntfs-through-dotnet) and that [blog](http://www.tunatoksoz.com/post/Transactional-File-System-Operations.aspx). Also [alphafs](http://alphafs.codeplex.com/) might be worth a look (they wrote a managed wrapper for the transaction ntfs) but I don't know the status of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `serializeObj(Object obj)` specifically serializes to a file:

```
List<string> FileNames = new List<string>();
try
{        
    serializeObj(obj1);
    //Add a method to determine the filename to which you wrote
    FileNames.Add(GetSerializedFileName(obj1)) 
    //repeat for all your objects
}
catch(Exception)
{
    Foreach(string fn in FileNames)
    {
        if(File.Exists(fn) File.Delete(fn);
    }
}
```

Assuming `serializeObj(Object obj)` simply writes to a memory stream for IO later it's even easier:

```
List<Stream> Files = new List<Stream>();
try
{        
    Files.Add(serializeObj(obj1));
    //repeat for all your objects
}
catch(Exception)
{
    Foreach(Stream fn in Files)
    {
        fn.Dipose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not a transaction. What if for some reason hardware stops to respond and force application to restart? If the fail happens during the obj3 serialization (in my pseudo-code) the obj1 and obj2 will stay in file system.

Comment: I've never used TransactionScope personally, but could you not just wrap it in a `using(TransactionScope myScope = new TransactionScope){}` block?

Comment: I think not. Anyway, that's part of my question! :)